# Удаление объекта из БД и combobox WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Ситуация следующая:
у меня есть База данных(БД) `Department` у этой БД два поля `id` и `DepName`. Задача: по нажатию кнопки "Удалить" - удалить объект из БД `Department` и `combobox`

Заполняю `combobox`так:

```
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionDb);

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, DepName FROM Department", connection);
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DepNamesBox.Items.Add(dr[1]);
            }
            dr.Close();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

SQL Команда на удаление:

```
        #region DeleteFunctionDep
        Query = "DELETE FROM Department WHERE ID = @ID";
        command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
        parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID");

        adapter.DeleteCommand = command;
        #endregion
```

"Button":

```
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)DepNamesBox.SelectedItem;
        drv.Row.Delete();
        adapter.Update(dt);
```

В итоге ошибка: **System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.String" к типу "System.Data.DataRowView"."**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно удалить объект из БД и `combobox` или к какому типу привести `DepNamesBox.SelectedItem`?

P.S. с `Listview` удалить объект получилось такой командой, а с `combobox` нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DepNamesBox.Items.Add(dr[1]);` - заполнять контрол object'ами прямо в запросе не лучший подход. 
Отделите представление от бизнес-логики. 
Пусть sql-запрос возвращает список `List<Departments>`.Держите его в памяти и работайте только с ним. А дальше дело нескольких шагов:

1: Приводите ваш object из бокса к `Department`; 
 2: Удаляете элемент сначала из бд передав ему `Department.id` из п.1; 
 3: Удаляете из списка в памяти; 
 4: Очистите `combobox` и заново отдайте ему оставшиеся элементы списка.

Таким образом вы убьете двух зайцев: упростите поддержание вашего кода и облегчите себе работу с данными.